# My hard drive is full when running solana-test-validator

Tags: solana-test-validator

My hard drive is full when running solana-test-validator. I run it on wsl2 on window. Has anyone had this problem and how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--limit-ledger-size` argument to `solana-test-validator`. Here's the help text:

```
        --limit-ledger-size <SHRED_COUNT>
            Keep this amount of shreds in root slots. [default: 10000]
```

Shreds are roughly 1kb, so the default should use up to ~10MB. Otherwise, the account data itself will also take up space, so be sure to avoid using too many large accounts.