# solana-test-validator RocksDB problem

Tags: solana-test-validator

I'm using solana-test-validator and over time the test-ledger folder starts to weigh a lot. I wanted to know how I could reduce that weight or if it can be compressed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My hard drive is full when running solana-test-validator](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6654/my-hard-drive-is-full-when-running-solana-test-validator)